# Angular 5 + Cordova

Tags: ios, angular, cordova, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm trying to build an angular app which I need to convert into iOS mobile application. I am able to create a new project in Cordova added iOS platform and built it. Now I have the xcode file with which I am able to generate app with just angular 5 code. Now I would like to know how to get the app version details from Cordova/Cordova plugins in my angular app.

Answer (score 0):

Found one.

Need to import Cordova.js manually to the index.html and sequence events are fired in app component.